# Tracking CiviContribute Contributions with a Google Goal Funnel

Tags: google

Has anyone figured out how to configure a Google Goal funnel (in Google Analytics) which will track CiviContribute contributions to the final thank  you page? It doesn't appear to be a topic with a solution. Thanks in advance for any help.